# Custom parser for mako

Tags: parsing, webkit, report, odoo, mako

I'm  trying to declare a custom parser but I'm getting an error.

```
NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",), <traceback object at 0xc336234>)".
```

Here's my code:

```
class print_task1(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(print_task1, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.dp_report_2','project.task','addons/exelixir_project/report/dp_report_2_1.mako',parser=print_task1,header="purchase_rep_webk_headq").
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class print_task1(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(print_task1, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time
        })

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.dp.report.2', 
                      'project.task',
                      'addons/exelixir_project/report/dp_report_2_1.mako', 
                       parser=print_task1,
                       header=header="purchase_rep_webk_headq")
```

If still not working than please check report tag (*name* attribute) just compare with *dp.report.2* In .py side we need to add only *report.report_name*

Comment: still having the problem.  thnks for your reply.

Comment: may you post report tag in your question ?

Comment: i want to generate print from a wizard. i wrote a function in a button on wizard. code is

Comment: code is :`def print_report1(self, cr, uid, ids, data, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        data = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[0]
        obj = self.pool.get('project.task').browse(cr,uid, data['task_id'][0])
        flag=0
        datas = {
             'ids': [data['task_id'][0]],
             'model': 'project.task',
             'form': data
                 }
return { 'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml', 'report_name': 'dp.tally1', 'datas': datas}`

Comment: try with `'report_name': 'dp.report.2'`